# Can't boot into bootloader on Oppo F1s

Tags: bootloader, oppo

I can't get into fastboot mode on my Oppo F1s (A1601), Android 5.1.

Here is what I'm doing:

- `adb` and `fastboot` are installed on Mac
- I have developer options and OEM unlock enabled
- In the terminal, `adb devices` shows my phone
- I enter `adb reboot-bootloader` but it does not say "fastboot mode" on the screen like I have read it is supposed to. It just restarts my phone. (note I have tried variations like `reboot_bootloader`; same result)

Am I doing it wrong or is fastboot not on this phone? Or is it hidden somehow?
The solution should be Mac supported, also I have windows 10 on a virtual machine.

Comment: Have you tried `adb reboot bootloader` instead?

Comment: [1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/oppo-a5-2020-root.3999639/post-82305395), [2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/3888013), [3](https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient#unlock-bootloader)